# aiohtttp connection pooling with ProxyConnector

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do connection pooling with aiohttp using the ProxyConnector as the connector?

The docs mention how to do this with the TcpConnector or using the Session class, but I can not seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ClientSession` object](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/v0.15.3/api.html#aiohttp.client.ClientSession), which handles connection pooling, takes a `connector` keyword argument:

> `class aiohttp.client.ClientSession(*, connector=None, loop=None, request_class=None, response_class=None, cookies=None, headers=None, auth=None)`

if no `connector` is given,  a `TCPConnector` will be used by default, but you can just specify a `ProxyConnector` instance, and that will be used instead. You can see this logic in the source:

```
class ClientSession:

    def __init__(self, *, connector=None, loop=None, request_class=None,
                 response_class=None, cookies=None, headers=None, auth=None):
        if loop is None:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._loop = loop
        self.cookies = http.cookies.SimpleCookie()
        if connector is None:
            connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, loop=loop)
```